# Use relative path to get all png files in python

Tags: python

Trying to retrieve all the paths of the pngs in different sub folders.

All sub folders are located within a main folder - logs.

```
pngs = []

for idx, device in enumerate(udid):
    pngs += glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/" + device + "_" + get_model_of_android_phone(device) + "/" + "*.png")
```

**File structure**

> logs/**123456789_SM-G920I**/**123456789google_search_android**.png

The values in bold will change. I have added in *.png for the changing pngs.

But how do i get the paths of the pngs when i do not have an absolute path to the png file?

**Update**

get_model_of_android_phone(device) is a method to get the following value here.

E.g. 123456789_SM-G920I

I am thinking to remove it cause it is not really working as intended. Would like to replace the method with something like *

Comment: what is `get_model_of_android_phone` doing?

Comment: `recursive=True` ?

Comment: what do you have in `pngs` ? Don't you have filenames with absolute path? `os.getcwd()` should append absolute path to all files.

Comment: Hi all, instead of using absolute path, is it possible to use relative paths? Because there are some issues getting the absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following in simplified way to get all file names:

```
for name in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/**/*.png", recursive=True):
    print '\t', name
```

When recursive is set, ** will matches 0 or more subdirectories when followed by a separator.

If you just want to make list, use the following code snippet :

```
pngs = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/**/*.png", recursive=True)
```

It will return a list of all png file paths.

Reference : https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Added the code to get all png path in a list. please check

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx, device in enumerate(udid):
    path_device = os.getcwd() + "/logs/" + device + "_" + get_model_of_android_phone(device) + "/"
    file_list = os.listdir(path_device)
    pngs = [path_device+file_png for file_png in file_list if str(file_png).endswith(".png")]
```